# Tcl/Tk always on top

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a Tcl/Tk application with multiple dialogs which may be visible at the same time.
However, I would like to set my “main dialog” (which is defined as top level) to be “always on top”. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
wm attribute . -topmost 1
```

Comment: I've tried it, but no good. Whenever additional dialog is opened, it covers the top level

Comment: On my windows machine, it behaves as advertised.

Comment: Idea: is it possible that your solution works when handling several top levels? In my application, I use 'dialog' widget from IWidgets.

Comment: If you specify `.` as parent of your dialog, then the dialog will inherit this. (e.g. `tk_chooseColor -parent .` will always be on top, the `.` window does not accept any input. The `wm attribute . -topmost 1` sets a system flag (always on top), so other programs like firefox are behind this window.

Comment: I understand. But I can I make a specific top level of my application to be always on top of all other IWidgets dialogs of the application?